# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, process, operating-system

I found similar questions but none of the solutions fixed my issue.
I started getting this error all of a sudden.

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=2,
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152

Command is:

```
svn list --xml "+unfuddlefileurl+" --no-auth-cache --username " + unfuddleUserName + " --password " + unfuddlePassword
```

This is my code:

```
 public static int runCommand(String command, String directory, String[] envp, File outputFile) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {                  
            logger.logDebug(CLASSNAME, "COMMAND is " + command + " directory = " + directory);          
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();      
            File workingDirectory = null;
            if (directory != null)
                workingDirectory = new File(directory);             
            Process proc = rt.exec(command, envp, workingDirectory);

            // any error message?            
            StreamConsumer errorGobbler = new 
            StreamConsumer(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR", outputFile);            

            // any output?
            StreamConsumer outputGobbler = new 
            StreamConsumer(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", outputFile);

            // kick them off
            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            // Note: This close() was added to make powershell commands work.            
            proc.getOutputStream().close();

            // any error???
            return proc.waitFor();            
    }
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why am I getting this error and how to fix that?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: Process proc = rt.exec(command, envp, workingDirectory); this line

Comment: «The system cannot find the file specified» is the answer to your question. Your Java process tries to [execute an external program named "svn"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[])) and fails. A shot in the dark is that the directory containing your `svn.exe` somehow gou out of `%PATH%`.

Comment: Can you please explain me a little more?  svn.exe is in C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin , this path is specified in environment variables

Comment: Sorry, I really cannot see what to explain here. Computers are deterministic; I mean, bit flips due to cosmic rays do indeed happen but you have a reliably reproducible case on your hands, so we can exclude such exotic reasons. So we're left with less exotic reasons, and the (only) way to deal with them is to 1) debug what is happening; 2) investigating what might have changed in the system. I'd go with (1). Like, print the contents of `%PATH%` supplied to the execution call,…

Comment: …verify that the same thing fails in `cmd.exe`—by doing `set PATH=that_contents_of_PATH; svn` and so on and so on. That's plain debugging of a simple problem; it's hardly possible to remotely help you further.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it

Comment: Adding PATH environment variable with svn path value in program's run configuration solved the issue